# using classes to in different scripts with python and pygame

Tags: python, class, pygame

I have recently started to make a game with python and pygame, I have a main script that has all my other scripts imported in and then it runs them all, but I have two main problems. The first being that when I run the first script in the main script it seems to stop after that class and not continue with the other script.

**what i want the game to do:**

show thee pictures as the opening credits. (working)

then once the credits are finished start up a menu, at the moment this is just one play button and a Rect which will have a collision response to detect whether the player has clicked it or not. (not working)

here are my scripts:

RUN.py (main game that runs everything together):

```
import pygame, random, math, sys, os, time
import startUp, Menu
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#classes setup
Begin = startUp.Begin()
Menu = Menu.HUD()
while True:

    #quit button 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()



    #show 3 pics for the opening credits
    Begin.Run()

    #bring up the menu once the opening credits are done
    Menu.Run()
```

Then Menu.py (the menu for the game)

```
import pygame, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

class HUD(object):

    def __init__(object):
        object.playButtonUp = "playButtonUp.png"
        object.playButtonUpHover = "playButtonUpHover.png"
        object.playButtonDown = "playButtonDown.png"

        object.Black = (0, 0, 0)
        object.Red = (0, 255, 0)
        object.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1440, 720), 0, 32)

        object.playButtonUp = pygame.image.load(object.playButtonUp).convert_alpha()
        object.playButtonUpHover = pygame.image.load(object.playButtonUpHover).convert_alpha()
        object.playButtonDown = pygame.image.load(object.playButtonDown).convert_alpha()

    def Run(object):
        #object.screen.fill(object.Black)

        #creat rects
        object.playButtonRect = Rect(464, 232, 256, 128)

        #blit imagers
        object.screen.blit(object.playButtonUp, (464, 232))
```

there are no error message's and it seems to work but the image is not shown on the screen.

thanks for you time and help!

Comment: Does `Begin.Run()` ends? By the way, the [standard python naming convention](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables) is to use lowercase for functions and methods names, and CapWords for class names.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `pygame` but is it okay to call `pygame.init()` twice?  You repeat that in `Menu.py`.

Comment: well that's what I need to do, get begin.Run() end, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is incorrect. You have merged two different approaches.

You have a Run script that should first show the 3 pictures, and after that show the menu.

Right now, you have a while loop that calls the run function of both Begin and Menu until you close the game.

Instead the files should look like this:

```
import pygame, random, math, sys, os, time
import startUp, Menu
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

#classes setup
Begin = startUp.Begin()
Begin.run()

Menu = Menu.HUD()
Menu.run()
```

Menu.py

```
class HUD(object):
    def run(object):
        while True:
            object.playButtonRect = Rect(464, 232, 256, 128)
            object.screen.blit(object.playButtonUp, (464, 232))
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
```